# What make, model and/or year is this SUV vehicle?

Tags: vehicle-identification

This question does not relate to one particular part of a vehicle, but the vehicle as a whole which is yet to be purchased, if ever. To do a substantial consideration, I would like to identify it, and I hope someone is able to name the make, model and/or year of it.

I have spent quite some time going through photos of SUV's, and failed to find it.

My guess would be Volkswagen or Subaru — each I appreciate for their price/value; I have no clue which model they would be, but my guess on its year is it probably is somewhere between 2012 and 2018.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the clearest image but I'd say that's a Z50 [Nissan Murano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Murano) (manuf.2002-2007)

The headlight cluster shape is pretty distinctive - and if you play with brightness/contrast a bit the the grill looks about right:

[image: Adjusted image for clarity]

Comment: Looks right. I have an 2011 Murano, 90.00 miles never any repairs, original brakes. My only complaint is the dash is difficult to see in strong daylight.

Comment: @motosubatsu Yep, that’s the one, thank you! The headlight is on the photo is a little misleading with that convex, but the grill does make the question clear.

Comment: @blacksmith37 thanks for the confirmation and the insights!